# Android HttpPost send empty $_POST to a PHP script

Tags: php, android, post

I have been trying to send a POST request to a URL from my Android App, but all that I get is a empty $_POST. Here is my code, it is running inside a Asynctask. I looked at several issues like this here in the StackOverflow, but none of them could help me.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.com/clients/app-controller/posts.php");

try {
      List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "John"));
      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post", "test123"));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

      post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

      String text = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
      System.out.println("STATUS CODE " +  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
      System.out.println("RETURN " +  text);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      System.out.println("ERROR1: " +  e.getStackTrace());
} catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("ERROR2: " + e.getStackTrace());
}
```

On the server side, I have a PHP test script testing if the $_POST variable are OK.

```
<?php echo "ISSET = " . isset($_POST["id"]) . isset($_POST["name"]) . isset($_POST["post"]); ?>
```

All that I get is a not set $_POST

```
STATUS CODE 200
RETURN ISSET =
```

I don't get any error warning and the App doesn't crash.

I tried to put the variables as a GET request attached to the URL and changed my PHP file to process the the $_GET request:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.com/clients/app-controller/posts.php?id=1234&name=John&post=test123");
```

It worked fine. I could read all $_GET variables in the PHP script. But I need it to be a POST request.

I have the INTERNET permission in my AndroidManifest.xml. In this same App I do requests for another PHP script and it work as expected.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please do var_dump($_POST) for debugging.

Comment: Not really a solution but more of suggestion: The Apache HTTP library in android [is very old and not maintained](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). You better off using HttpsUrlConnection or a library like retrofit.

Comment: When I do a var_dump($_POST) I get "RETURN array(0) { }"

Comment: There is no problem while running the above code on my local web server. var_dump result: `array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "John"
  ["post"]=>
  string(7) "test123"
}`

Comment: I put the PHP script in another server, and it worked! But I still need to figure out the problem with the first server because I that's the server that it should actually run. What could be causing the server to reject the POST request? Once that the the Response Status Code is 200 the URL is right.

Comment: Is the server behind a proxy?

Answer (score -1):

If your HttpPost URL has **"www"** remove it and try. If not add www.

Because, you might have redirected **yoursite.com** to **www.yoursite.com** or vice versa. In such cases, your HttpPost URL should be the designation URL and not the redirecting URL. The parameters will be lost during the HTTP redirection process and a empty POST will be done. This is why the server is not receiving your post data.