# Use of $_POST when php file is called by android app

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to upload some data in the database with an android app. Until now everything was working fine, but now I need to add another column, so I modified the code and now it looks like the data sent by the phone is not readable by my php files. The important part of the code of my app is the following:

```
private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
        throws IOException {

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(endpoint);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
    }
    StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();
    // constructs the POST body using the parameters
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
        bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                .append(param.getValue());
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            bodyBuilder.append('&');
        }
    }
    String body = bodyBuilder.toString();
    Log.v(TAG, "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);
    byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        Log.e("URL", "> " + url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        //conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        // post the request
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        Log.v(TAG, "Has posted" + bytes);
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();
        // handle the response
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != 200) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Post Failed");
            throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
        }
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

On the Logcat it looks like the app has been able to post the code effectively in byte format:

```
V/Alvaro Lloret GCM﹕ Posting email=llor&name=hola&arduinoweb=jaj&regId=APA' to http://youdomotics.com/mysecurity1/register.php
E/URL﹕ > http://website.com/mysecurity1/register.php
V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
V/RenderScript﹕ 0xaec16400 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
V/Alvaro Lloret GCM﹕ Has posted[B@16d173b0
V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2015-09-11 20:21:30.364
V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Releasing wakelock
```

Then, the code to receive the post with php is the following:

```
<?php
// response json
$json = array();

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"]) ) { 
     require("config.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $arduinoweb = $_POST["arduinoweb"];
    $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID
    include_once './gcm.php';
    $query = "INSERT INTO gcm_users_new(name, email, gcm_regid, arduinoweb, created_at) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$gcm_regid', '$arduinoweb', NOW())";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
} else {
    // user details missing
}

?>
```

This code worked perfectly without the new parameter arduinoweb, but since I added this other parameter, the row is not added into the database. If I comment the condition if (isset...), then the file adds a row in the table, but it's empty...

Any ideas?

Thank you!!

Comment: $_POST["name"] will accept the name as params sended from android similarly other params are accepted in php from android

Comment: I don't think that the problem is neither with the code in the android app not in the php file, maybe is the server, which is in goDaddy, but i really can't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved!

The perfect answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123335/android-httppost-send-empty-post-to-a-php-script)

I just had to change to www. when I called the URL and that made it work!